# Is laptop external display button OS specific?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell Inspiron N4010 with a busted LCD.  I can boot into Windows 7 just fine with it and I can hit Fn-F1 to output video over HDMI.

I want to install a headless Arch Linux on this laptop, but I'm afraid that I won't be able to run the installer if I can't see what I'm doing.

Is Fn-F1 an OS (i.e., Windows) specific thing or will that work regardless of OS?

Comment: Arc-Linux has a Live CD option, so try it. I am fairly certain that after booting to Live CD the results of trying Fn-F1 are going to be the same on both the Live CD and on installed versions. If it does not work as excepted you can try and make it work before committing to a permanent installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination to project to a second screen (`Fn + something`) is **not OS specific**. It depends on the make and model, for example the combination for my Acer laptop is `Fn + F5`, while some HP models use `Fn + F4`; hence it cannot be OS specific.

Another proof is that **the combination works even in BIOS** ("pre-OS").

So you'll be able to see the installation progress - just remember that sometimes it restarts so you may have to press the combination again. If you press it in the BIOS then you'll also have to press it again when booting from your live CD/USB.

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't [depend on the OS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62319/is-there-an-equivalent-to-win-p-switch-video-output-hotkey)?

Comment: @fooot the combination of `Win+something` is Windows (obviously... Win), but `Fn+something`, where the "something" key has the switch display icon, depends on the model. And since `Fn+something` works in the BIOS, it cannot depend on the OS only.

Comment: I had to hit F12 to get to the boot menu so I could boot from USB, but I was still able to use the Fn-F1 combo to display the boot menu to my external monitor.  I was then able to run arch live.

Answer (score 0):

Some keys are managed by BIOS but others must be managed by the OS. It should not be surprising if they work in BIOS, because the BIOS is made for the specific hardware. There are many threads out there with people trying to get brightness controls, suspend/hibernate, volume, and other functions to work correctly. Something like Ubuntu is more likely to work "out of the box" than Arch, but as arch-abit suggests, the best way is to just try it and see if it works. I couldn't find anything specific to your model.

The system might be smart enough to use an external display if it is connected at startup, but if not, it could be difficult to resolve.

[This thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188599) describes someone trying to get their display switch function to work (no solution posted).

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/124761/tool-for-making-fn-x-buttons-work-archlinux-handler-sh) has some tips for getting the function keys to work.

[The Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hotkeys) has some tips on dealing with various hotkeys.